# Postgres DECIMAL custom ORDER BY function for zero values

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

Zero values of the `DECIMAL` data type in postgres do not seem to be ordered. How can I adjust the `ORDER BY` function so that a number with many decimal zeros is smaller than a number with fewer decimal zeros (or the other way around)?

[image]

An ascending order of values should look like this:

```
0.00000000000
0.000000
0.000
0.0
```

Comment: `order by dec_amount, scale(dec_amount)`  maybe?

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for!

Comment: Not sure what the purpose is?: `select 0.00000000000::numeric = 0; t, select 0.000::numeric = 0; t` So you are not getting an order of value, but an order of scale.